# What is options notBefore in auth0 node-jsonwebtoken for?

Tags: jwt, auth0

I am reading https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback documentation.

It says:

> - `notBefore`: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span [zeit/ms](https://github.com/zeit/ms).
>
>   > Eg: `60`, `"2 days"`, `"10h"`, `"7d"`. A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default (`"120"` is equal to `"120ms"`).

What is this options for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this document

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

The section `4.1.5.  "nbf" (Not Before) Claim`

```
The "nbf" (not before) claim identifies the time before which the JWT
   MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of the "nbf"
   claim requires that the current date/time MUST be after or equal to
   the not-before date/time listed in the "nbf" claim.  Implementers MAY
   provide for some small leeway, usually no more than a few minutes, to
   account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number containing a
   NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.
```